# ¿Como obtener el id de las imagenes que aun no se encuentran en la tabla respuestas para un determinado test?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy intentando obtener las imágenes que aun no se encuentran en la tabla respuestas para un determinado test y de un determinado paciente.

Por ejemplo: todas las imágenes que pertenezcan al `testid = 1` y  no hayan sido incluidas como respuestas en el `TestPacientesID= 3` de la tabla respuestas.

¿Como podría resolverlo?

Tengo las siguientes tablas en `mariadb 10`:

- Pacientes
- Tests
- Imagenes
- Respuestas

Adjunto capturas:

**Pacientes**

[image: Captura-de-pantalla-de-2021-06-23-22-43-19.png]

**Tests**
[image: Captura-de-pantalla-de-2021-06-23-22-40-59.png]

**Imágenes**

[image: Imagenes.png]

**Respuestas**

[image: Respuestas.png]

Hasta el momento intente con esto:

intento 1:

```
select i.Nombre , i.TestID from imagenes i 
where not exists 
(select 1 from respuestas r where r.ArchivoID = i.ImagenID);
```

[image: Captura-de-pantalla-de-2021-06-23-22-53-09.png]

Intento 2:

```
select * from imagenes i 
left join respuestas r on r.ArchivoID = i.ImagenID
left join testpacientes t on t.TestPacienteID = r.TestPacienteID 
where i.TestID =1 and r.RespuestaID is null;
```

[image: Captura-de-pantalla-de-2021-06-23-22-58-15.png]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con Not INT, cuando unas las tablas pones Where imagenid NOT INT (Select imagenid from.... )  esto te escogera las imágenes que no estén dentro del resultado de la subconsulta NOT INT (Select..... )